# form.elements.filter is not a function when trying to weed out button inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays

`form.elements` returns an array like so...

```
[
     input#user_name, 
     input#user_email,
     button#submit,
     ...
]
```

I'm trying to filter out the button inputs

```
<button type="submit" className="btn" id="edit">Save</button>

form.elements.filter(i => (
    i.tagName !== 'BUTTON'
)).forEach(i => (// store stuff));
```

Why wouldn't this work? returns `form.elements.filter is not a function`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`form.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) returns a [`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection).

`filter` does not exist as an operation on a HTMLFormControlsCollection, along with some other array methods, like `forEach`.

You could convert to an array first in a number of ways. As pointed out by @DavidThomas, since you are using arrow functions you should be able to use `Array.from`

```
var els = Array.from(form.elements);
// Otherwise, use [].slice.call(form.elements)
```

Now you can do any array operations normally, including `forEach`, `filter`, etc.

```
els = els.filter(el => (
    el.tagName !== 'BUTTON'
))
```

---

**Here is a full example:**

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var els = Array.from(form.elements);

els = els.filter(el => {
  return (
    el.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'button' &&
    el.getAttribute('type') !== 'button'
  );
});

els.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="1">
  <input type="button" value="Input Button">
  <textarea>Awesome Content</textarea>
  <button>Another Button</button>
  <button type="submit" className="btn" id="edit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Great explanation thank you :) I converted the array, but it doesn't seem to be filtering out the button

Comment: @Modelesq, your button is probably an `input` with a `type` of `button`. In order to capture that, you will have to do it with an additional check. I've updated my answer to reflect that scenario.

Comment: @Modelesq, and make sure to reset the variable for the filter function after you've converted it to an array:
`elArray = elArray.filter(...)`
Updated answer to reflect that

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The button is still in there I also tried `el.type !== 'submit'` doesn't seem to want to disappear. On a different note: what would you suggest for dealing with `forEach`? (I'd like to keep it in one query)

Comment: @Modelesq, if you could include the HTML for the button that is not being removed in your question, that would be helpful. When you say deal with `forEach`, what do you mean?

Comment: updated my post. (nvm about the forEach forgot we converted to proper array)

Comment: @Modelesq I added your HTML button code to my answer. And when I run the code snippet, it filters it out. As an extra precaution, I call `toLowerCase()` on the tagName and compare to a lowercase tagName. When you run my code snippet, does it not work?

Comment: If Arrow functions are available to the OP there's a good chance that s/he also has access to [`Array.from(form.elements)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), rather than using the older `Array.slice.call(form.elements)` approach.

Comment: Your answer clearly works. I'm not sure why this isn't working for me, but thats another problem. Thank you for your help kind sir! :D

Comment: @Modelesq, glad I could help. But it's still a bummer that it's not working for you in your code, and that's the goal here. Let me know if you've got other questions, maybe I can get some time to help through StackOverflow chat or something.

Comment: Found the problem. It was my forEach at the end `.filter(i => (
    i.tagName !== 'BUTTON'
)).forEach(i => (// store stuff));`

Comment: @Modelesq. Ah! Yeah, `forEach` doesn't return a new array like `filter` does. Good catch. Glad you got it working!

Comment: Is there a way to keep this in one line with forEach?

Comment: You could use `.map` instead of `.forEach` and return the item when you are done with it instead. The first comment in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228064/why-can-array-prototype-foreach-not-be-chained) talks about that. That question also addresses your question to me. So I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If performance ever becomes an issue, remember that you can "merge" the `.filter` call into `Array.from` by taking advantage of the fact that `HTMLFormControlsCollection` is "Array-like":

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var els_coll = form.elements;

els_array = Array.prototype.filter.call(els_coll, el => {
  return (
    el.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'button' &&
    el.getAttribute('type') !== 'button'
  );
});

els_array.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="1">
  <input type="button" value="Input Button">
  <textarea>Awesome Content</textarea>
  <button>Another Button</button>
  <button type="submit" className="btn" id="edit">Save</button>
</form>
```